# Reset back to previous option on Select field if js Confirm returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML select field. Where one option is `selected`. If I select any other `change` even fires and confirm prompt is shown.

What I want is when user cancel the confirmation aka `conf` is `false`. I want to reset back to the previous selected option. But currently the new option is selected.

### HTML

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Foo0</option>
    <option seleted="selected">Foo1</option>
    <option>Foo3</option>
    <option>Foo4</option>
    <option>Foo5</option>
    <option>Foo6</option>
</select>
```

### js/jq

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   var select = $('#mySelect');
   select.change(function(){
     var conf = confirm('Are You Sure?');
     if(!conf){
         // reset the select back to previous
         return;
     }

     // do stuff

  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I created a jsfiddle for you here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/CZ8F9/

I am just saving the previous index.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   var index = $('#mySelect').prop('selectedIndex'); 
    var select = $('#mySelect');
   select.change(function(e){
       alert(index)
     var conf = confirm('Are You Sure?');
     if(!conf){
             $('#mySelect').prop('selectedIndex',index);
         // reset the select back to previous
         return false;
     }
       else{
       index= $('#mySelect').prop('selectedIndex');}

     // do stuff

  });
});
```

Comment: I want to do exactly the same thing albeit in angular 2:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142367/angular-2-changes-in-ngmodel-not-reflecting-in-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

put your oldvalue as data and get it back when it selected wrong...

```
 var select = $('#mySelect');
   select.click(function(){
        $(this).data("oldval", this.value);
    }).change(function(){
     var conf = confirm('Are You Sure?');
     if(!conf){
        $(this).val($(this).data("oldval"));
     }  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.focus()` to store the previously selected option on focus, which will be triggered before the selection is changed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var select = $('#mySelect');
    var previouslySelected;

    select.focus(function(){
        previouslySelected = this.value;
    }).change(function(){
     var conf = confirm('Are You Sure?');
     if(!conf){
         // reset the select back to previous
         this.value = previouslySelected;
         return;
     }

     // do stuff
    alert('Doing stuff');
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9mAHP/1/

Answer (score 0):

You weren't looking for something like this, were you? Just store the value, then grab it when you need it.

```
$(document).ready(function($){   
   var select = $('#mySelect');
   var current = $('#mySelect').find(":selected").text();
   select.change(function(){
     var conf = confirm('Are You Sure?');
     if(!conf){
         select.val(current);
     } else{
         // do stuff
     }
     current = $('#mySelect').find(":selected").text();
     // reset the select back to previous
     return;
  });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Qw6K9/