# Angular 2- changes in ngModel not reflecting in dropdown

Tags: angular

So I have a very simple scenario where there's a confirmation popup to be shown on dropdown change. If the user chooses to cancel, I need to revert the dropdown value to old one. I think I'm doing correctly and even in the DOM, value of ngModel bound with `select` is reflecting. But somehow it's not reverting the selected value in display. Here's my code

```
<select style="display: inline-block;width: 20%" class="form-control" 
  name="selectedClientVersion" 
  (change)="selectedCurrentVersion($event.target.value)" 
           [(ngModel)]="selectedClientVersion">
           <option *ngFor="let i of clientVersions" 
           [selected]="i == 'selectedClientVersion' ">{{i}}</option>
  </select>

selectedClientVersion='version1';
  prevSelectedClientVersion='version1';
  clientVersions=['version1', 'version2', 'version3'];
  selectedCurrentVersion(val){
    var r = confirm("Do you really want to chnage?");
    if (r == true) {
        this.prevSelectedClientVersion= this.selectedClientVersion= val;

    } else {
       this.selectedClientVersion=this.prevSelectedClientVersion;
       //return false;
    }
  }
```

P.S I tried `ngModelChange` too in place of `change`.
Update: I have already searched on stackOverflow for similar answer and found none of the scenario handles this case where there's an involvement of confirmation popup and the values have to be reverted based on that in `Angular 2`

[image][image]

UPDATE2: This is what I want to do, albeit in angular 2:
[Reset back to previous option on Select field if js Confirm returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038594/reset-back-to-previous-option-on-select-field-if-js-confirm-returns-false)
http://jsfiddle.net/CZ8F9/

Comment: @Aravind Please read and understand the question carefully. don't make assumptions just by reading the title

Comment: Remove quotes from `selectedClientVersion` in  `[selected]="i == 'selectedClientVersion' "` and write as `[selected]="i == selectedClientVersion "`

Comment: I m sorry. check my answer below

Comment: @SaiUnique yeah done those already. all possible trial and errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I could come up with is to create a reference of the previously selected object/value and pass it with the function when `ngModelChange` triggers it. I had to some research on how to set value for `select` from component. Here's my example code:

html:

```
<select #selectBox
            [(ngModel)]="selectedClientVersion" 
            (ngModelChange)="selectedCurrentVersion(prevSelectedClientVersion, selectedClientVersion, selectBox)" 
            (focus)="prevSelectedClientVersion=selectedClientVersion">
        <option *ngFor="let i of clientVersions" 
                [ngValue]="i"> 
          {{ i.value }}
        </option>
 </select>
```

component.ts:

```
selectedCurrentVersion(prevObj, currObj, selectbox){

    var r = confirm("Do you really want to change?");
    if (r == true) {
      this.selectedClientVersionObj = currObj;
    }
    else{
      selectbox.selectedIndex = this.clientVersions.indexOf(prevObj);
      this.selectedClientVersionObj = prevObj;
      this.selectedClientVersion = prevObj;
    }

}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xB92Mw?p=preview)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks this works :) However, just wonder why we still need to manipulate DOM through javascript . It  would have been better handling in pure Angular2. Isn't it?

Comment: I have updated the answer to pass DOM element reference instead of using `document`, that's the most angularish solution I can think of :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an empty option

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
    <option [ngValue]="''"></option>
      <option *ngFor="let value of values$ | async"
              [ngValue]="value">{{ value }}
      </option>
    </select>


reset(){
    this.selectedValue='';
  }
```

**Note:** You are not using `ngValue` without which selected item is not assigned to `ngModel` variable

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ld6K0LcDV5tOi8YFhZif?p=preview)**

Comment: It's fine if you trigger it from an external button. But I have to get it through on change method

Comment: use `(ngModelChange)` event instead of `(change)`. Refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610183/angular-2-passing-data-into-a-for-loop/44610213#44610213)